# How to add a value in object in catch part?

Tags: java, stored-procedures

I have the following method in my project. When I catch an SQLException, like `Duplicate entry '505051' for key 'ID_UNIQUE'`, I like to add a message to `obj`.

However, line `obj.put (e.getMessage());` tells me `Null pointer access: The variable obj can only be null at this location`. Do you know of how to add a sting in obj?

```
public JSONArray insert_patient_data(String name, String surname) {
        JSONArray obj = null;
        Connection conn = this.getDBMySQLCon();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String queryString = "CALL insert_patient (?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = null;
        try {
            preparedStmt = conn.prepareCall(queryString);
            preparedStmt.setString(1, name);
            preparedStmt.setString(2, surname);


            boolean results = preparedStmt.execute();
            int rowsAffected = 0;


            conn.close();
            return obj;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
            obj.put (e.getMessage());
            return obj;
  }
```

Comment: Your `JSONArray obj = null;` is declared as null and  not changed. Instantiate it using `new` keyword. `JSONArray obj = new JSONArray();`

Comment: Look at line 2 of your code. There you set `obj` to `null`. Nowhere else are you assigning anything to `obj`, so when execution reaches the `obj.put(...)` line, it will always be `null`, which will lead to a `NullPointerException` when you would run it. Make sure that `obj` actually refers to an object.

Comment: Try using e.Tostring to print the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the obj.
In the second line you have wrote `JSONArray obj = null;` and you never created a new JSONArray.
So, when you write `obj.put (e.getMessage());`, obj is still null! And this is the cause of your error message.

Try to do:

```
 JSONArray obj = new JSONArray();
```

Then, your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize your obj to null, and never set it, before using it in the catch instruction.

At least, you should instantiate it with a non-null Object:

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray();
```